# AUTH0 Access Token

Tags: auth0

I have given an AUTH0 login URL, username, and password. I have logged in a  service fine using the browser.

Now I want to duplicate this login flow using Python, and get back the **Auth0 Access Token**, which autho0 API endpoint should I use?

Comment: Auth0 Employee here, What are you exactly trying to achieve? Are you trying to login to an app, a web app (server), cli or a single page app ? Why is the hosted login flow not a viable option in this case? For just an API backed login you can use https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant#realm-support however, I would recommend using the browser flow in all scenarios. For example, for an SPA / WebApp you'll need to use https://auth0.com/docs/cross-origin-authentication instead in order to set the session cookie if you want to extend your session.

Comment: I can't use the browser flow anymore because of internal requirement.

Comment: The password grant should work however, we strongly recommend using hosted flow.